# How write a Python program to retrieve all the products from the API Server

Tags: python, json

> Suppose you are writing a Python web client to access an API of an online supermarket. Given below are the API details.
>
> Base URL = http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080
>
> Write a Python program to retrieve all the products from the API Server and print the total number of products currently stored in the server.
>
> Hint: the JSON response will be of the following example format:

```json
{
  "message": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 85,
      "productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice",
      "description": "White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",
      "category": "Rice",
      "brand": "CIC",
      "expiredDate": "2023.05.04",
      "manufacturedDate": "2022.02.20",
      "batchNumber": 324567,
      "unitPrice": 1020,
      "quantity": 200,
      "createdDate": "2022.02.24"
    },
    {
      "id": 86,
      "productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice",
      "description": "White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",
      "category": "Rice",
      "brand": "CIC",
      "expiredDate": "2023.05.04",
      "manufacturedDate": "2022.02.20",
      "batchNumber": 324567,
      "unitPrice": 1020,
      "quantity": 200,
      "createdDate": "2022.02.24"
    }
  ]
}
```

The answer for the above question is the code below.

```py
import requests
import json

BASE_URL = "http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080"
updated_entity = {
"productName":"Araliya Basmathi Rice",
"description":"White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",
"category":"Rice",
"brand":"Araliya",
"expiredDate":"2023.05.04",
"manufacturedDate":"2022.02.20",
"batchNumber":324567,
"unitPrice":1020,
"quantity":200,
"createdDate":"2022.02.24"
}

response = requests.put(f"{BASE_URL}/api/products/", json=updated_entity)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: This endpoint is not returning any product . It's only returning this ' {message":"University of Moratuwa"} '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great! So it sounds like you were able to fetch the JSON response successfully.
**Mind you**, `response_API` is NOT the JSON, it is just a Response object. You need to call .json() or .text() on it to get the result you intend. Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_response.asp

You’ll now need to parse the JSON string into a useable Python data structure.

Here is information for parsing JSON: https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_json_parse.asp

```
parsed = json.load(response_API.text())
```

JSON is parsed into a dictionary. Here you can access the “data” key, which is a list of products. We can simply get the length of a list.

```
len(parsed[“data”])
```

Answer (score 0):

4.7 API Quiz 2

```
import requests   # Import request to get data from API
import json       # Import JSON to convert the data to json

BASE_URL = "http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080/api/products"

# Get request to get the data from API
response = requests.get(BASE_URL)

# Response convert to json
json_items = response.json()

# Convert json_items to readable (str) format using indentation
json_format = json.dumps(json_items, indent = 2)

# Need to count the number of items in the json_format to get the total
total = json_format.count('productName')
print(total)
```